# Jar Files not working when I include external dependencies in my project in Intellij

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, intellij-idea, jar

I am using Java JDK Version 11 and Intellij IDEA

Case 1:

I created a simple maven project, created a class named Main and then a main function inside it and wrote some code.

```
package org.example;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.printf("Hello and welcome!");
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {

            
            System.out.println("i = " + i);
        }
    }
}
```

My POM.XML file in this case looks like -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyProject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

</project>
```

Then I created a jar of this Main.java file and tried to run using "java -jar CreatedJarname.jar". It runs and gives the output successfully

Case 2:

Now I wanted to work with spark. So, I included some external jars in my project using this UI.

[image: Adding external dependencies]

In the attached pic, you can see the added dependencies named "activation-1.1.1 jar and 242 more files".
Now, I am able to use spark in my project. However my pom.xml has remained unchanged. It didn't get updated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyProject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

</project>
```

Also, now when I create a jar using the same code in the main method as above, and use the command "java -jar CreatedJarname.jar" to run it, I am getting the error -

Error: Could not find or load main class org.example.Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.example.Main

So, now I am very confused, just adding external dependencies to my project causes my jar files to have an error. Also, my pom.xml is not getting updated when adding these dependencies. I have tried looking over the web but I am not able to find any solution.

Comment: Why you're trying to merge both Intellij build and Maven build at the same time? If you're building your .jar using Maven, you need to add the needed dependency via Maven. Vice versa for Intellij build.

Comment: @yahorbarkouski I have created a maven project but I am building .jar using Intellij and also adding dependencies using Intellij.

Comment: If you're doing something like that in IntelliJ (which I don't use) and changes are not reflected in pom.xml then it's not using Maven or is doing so in a way which breaks Maven. So you need to find out how to get them to play nicely together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two misunderstandings:

1. If this is a Maven project, you need to add all dependencies in the `pom.xml`.
2. To make a JAR executable, you need to build it with the Maven Assembly Plugin or the Maven Shade Plugin. Normal JARs do not include their dependencies.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did both and its working now :)